# On input, increase initial state from 0.00 to 0.01 and on subsequent input, increase to 0.11

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the title states, I have an input. The initial state of that input is 0.00. If a user enters a number, as an example: `1`, the new value will be `0.01` for example. On the subsequent input, the value would then be `0.11`. I believe I have the function portion figured out properly, increasing the number, however I immediately get stuck in an infinite loop as soon as I enter a number. Below should be the minimum to replicate my code:

```
import { useState, forwardRef } from 'react'
import { TextField } from '@mui/material'
import { NumericFormat } from 'react-number-format';


const Example = (props) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    minSpend: '0.00'
  })

  const handleMinChange = (event) => {
    const newValue = parseFloat(event.target.value * 1000)
    if (!isNaN(newValue)) {
      setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
        ...prevFormData,
        minSpend: ((prevFormData.minSpend * 10 + newValue) / 100).toFixed(2),
      }))
    }
  }
  
  return (
     <TextField
       fullWidth
       name='minSpend'
       label='Min Spend'
       value={formData.minSpend}
       onChange={handleMinChange}
       InputProps={{
         inputComponent: NumericFormatCustom,
       }}
      />
     )
    }
```

I don't know if this is applicable but:

```
const NumericFormatCustom = forwardRef(function NumericFormatCustom(props, ref) {
  const { onChange, ...other } = props

  return (
    <NumericFormat
      {...other}
      getInputRef={ref}
      onValueChange={(values) => {
        onChange({
          target: {
            name: props.name,
            value: values.value,
          }
        })
      }}
      thousandSeparator
      prefix='$'
      decimalSeparator="."
      allowDecimal
      allowNegative={false}
    />
  )
})

NumericFormatCustom.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

The function above is just to format it properly, so it has the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled it a bit differently, and instead of doing `0.00` as my initial value, I did `0`. Because of that, if I add a value to it, the resulting output would be `01`. To get rid of the leading zero, I passed the subsequent value to `parseFloat` to get rid of the leading zero. Then, because I wanted to add decimal places trailing afterwards, I had a regex check to see if the value has any trailing values after the decimal place. If it did not, then they were appended onto it using the `toFixed(2)` function.

The new `handleMinSpendChange` function looks as follows:

```
const handleMinChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target

    const hasTwoDecimalPlaces = /\.\d{2}$/.test(value)

    setFormData(
      {
        ...formData,
        [name]: hasTwoDecimalPlaces ? value : parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)
      }
    )
  }
```